# The list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected on 3d arrays

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm learning to build a neural network with `Sequential` from `keras` but I'm getting an error when I run this:

```
X = [
    [[1,4,5],[7,8,15],[13,16,45],[19,32,135]],
    [[0,0,0],[1,4,9], [16,25,36],[49,64,82]],
    [[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [1,1,1], [2,2,2]]
]

y = [
 [[25,64,405], [31,128,1215]],
 [[100,121,144], [169,196, 225]],
 [[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]   
]
X= np.array(X)
Y= np.array(y)

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(4, 3)))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
# fit network
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=4)
return model
```

```
Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 3 arrays:
```

I thought Sequential was supposed to take in a 3d array where I specified the number of `timesteps=4` and `features=3` , but it looks like something's not right with my formatting. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you fit the model to **y** and to to ***Y*** .
Secondly, Y should be a (None, 3) array, as your network outputs 3 values, but Y is (None, 2, 3).

Begin by correcting these errors and will see if something goes wrong afterwards

Comment: Thanks for the typo catch! But I think my Y is a (3,4,3) array? Shouldn't the last layer only have 3 nodes for each feature? I'm not understanding how Y is (None,2,3), or why it should be a (None,3) array.



Basically I'm expecting the my `model` to take  in the first 2d list in `X` and give back something similar to the first 2d list in `Y`, then take in the second 2d list in `X` and give back the second 2d list in `Y` and so on - at least that's how I understood my encoding, though not sure if it's consistent with what my code is doing.

Comment: Your X is (None, 4, 3). Your Y is (None, 2, 3). Y should be (None, 3)

Comment: I'm not getting `(None,4,3)`. `print(X.shape)` returns `(3,4,3)` and `print(Y.shape)` returns `(3,2,3)`.

Comment: I am saying None because the first dimension is not affecting the network.

Comment: I see - in that case, I still want my output `Y` to have the next two items for each series predicted in the future, with each item having 3 features, so I believe my Y should still be of shape`(3,2,3).` 


Is this not possible with Sequential, or how should I modify my code to receive my output in my desired format?

Comment: There are several ways to handle it. I suggest to feed the prediction for the first time step to the model for prediction of the second time step.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions! The model finally runs without errors, but now I'm trying to get the model to predict better - strangely enough, each element predicted is a value between 0 and 1 - although my Y values are typically whole numbers greater than 1... any suggestions on what to do here?

Comment: Maybe use activation=‘relu’ in the last layer too?

Comment: Yup that did it - Also increasing the number of epochs helped as well!